# Change date format after eloquent query laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, date-format, php-carbon

After I execute this query:

```
public function qryRecords($id)
    {
        $records = Record::with('place.country', 'place.city', 'place.organisation', 'framework', 'academy_year', 'status', 'type', 'student')
            ->where('student_id', '=', $id)
            ->get();

        return response()->json($records);
    }
```

I'd like to change the date format of academy_year, this is how it is kept in my database:

```
[
                    'start_date' => '2015-09-01',
                    'created_at' => now(),
                    'end_date' => '2016-06-30',
                    'is_archived' => true
                ],
```

Now in my model I do this to get the dates in datatables:

```
{
                        data: null,
                        render: function (data) {
                            return data.academy_year.start_date + ' <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> <br> ' + data.academy_year.end_date;
                        }
                    },
```

I know of the method Carbon, but I'm not sure on how to use this in my situation.
If it is possible with Carbon, I would love to hear, also if there are other methods I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine with an additional library, you could try Moment.js.

For example:

```
{
  data: null,
  render: function (data) {
    var formatted_start_date = moment(data.academy_year.start_date).format('dd.mm.yyyy')
    var formatted_end_date = moment(data.academy_year.end_date).format('dd.mm.yyyy')
    return formatted_start_date + ' <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> <br> ' + formatted_end_date;
 }
},
```

Please refer to the formatting docs if you want it to be formatted differently.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of doing this, and the second option layers together with the first:

1. Use a date mutator in your model(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Record model:

```
protected $dates = [
        'start_date',
        'end_date'
    ];
```

Then, where you want to use the date into your custom format do this:

```
$record->start_date->format('d-m-Y');//Customize format as you want.
```

I would use this option, if the format does not need to change in the future, and only needs to be used a couple of times.

2. Use an accessor(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor): (use in combination with answer 1)

Record model:

```
function getFormattedStartDateAttribute()
{
    return $this->start_date->format('d-m-Y');
}
```

When you want the formatted date, you can do:

```
$record->formatted_start_date;
```

I prefer the second option, because then you have to define the output format once, and then use $record->formatted_start_date every time you want the 'front-end-format'

Let me know if it works for you :)